# Sorting elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have this requirements to sort the particular element. But I don't know how will I do that. I tried the XSLT that I've seen but I can't get the expected output that I wanted. The input XML is like this:

```
<SyncCredit xmlns="http://schema.XYZ.com/XYZOAGIS/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" releaseID="9.2" versionID="2.12.3">
  <Data>
    <AccountingNo>ERP_12344</AccountingNo>
    <Credit>
      <Header>
        <Name>Supplier Bank</Name>
        <Date>02-08-2017</Date>
      </Header>
      <Payment>
        <ID>111</ID>
        <Date>02-01-2017</Date>
        <Transaction>
          <BookNo>AA-111</BookNo>
          <Creditor>
            <PartyID>
              <ID schemeName="PassportNo">1000</ID>
            </PartyID>
          </Creditor>
        </Transaction>
        <Transaction>
          <BookNo>AA-111</BookNo>
          <Creditor>
            <PartyID>
              <ID schemeName="TaxIdentificationNo">5000</ID>
            </PartyID>
          </Creditor>
        </Transaction>
      </Payment>
      <Payment>
        <ID>222</ID>
        <Date>02-05-2017</Date>
        <Transaction>
          <BookNo>AA-111</BookNo>
          <Creditor>
            <PartyID>
              <ID schemeName="BankPartyNo">4000</ID>
            </PartyID>
          </Creditor>
        </Transaction>
        <Transaction>
          <BookNo>AA-111</BookNo>
          <Creditor>
            <PartyID>
              <ID schemeName="DriverLicense">2000</ID>
            </PartyID>
          </Creditor>
        </Transaction>
      </Payment>
    </Credit>
  </Data>
</SyncCredit>
```

My expected output should look like this:

```
<SyncCredit xmlns="http://schema.XYZ.com/XYZOAGIS/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" releaseID="9.2" versionID="2.12.3">
  <Data>
    <AccountingNo>ERP_12344</AccountingNo>
    <Credit>
      <Header>
        <Name>Supplier Bank</Name>
        <Date>02-08-2017</Date>
      </Header>
      <Payment>
        <ID>111</ID>
        <Date>02-01-2017</Date>
        <Transaction>
          <BookNo>AA-111</BookNo>
          <Creditor>
            <PartyID>
              <ID schemeName="PassportNo">1000</ID>
            </PartyID>
          </Creditor>
        </Transaction>
      </Payment>
      <Payment>
        <ID>222</ID>
        <Date>02-05-2017</Date>
        <Transaction>
          <BookNo>AA-111</BookNo>
          <Creditor>
            <PartyID>
              <ID schemeName="DriverLicense">2000</ID>
            </PartyID>
          </Creditor>
        </Transaction>
      </Payment>
      <Payment>
        <ID>222</ID>
        <Date>02-05-2017</Date>
        <Transaction>
          <BookNo>AA-111</BookNo>
          <Creditor>
            <PartyID>
              <ID schemeName="BankPartyNo">4000</ID>
            </PartyID>
          </Creditor>
        </Transaction>
      </Payment>
      <Payment>
        <ID>111</ID>
        <Date>02-01-2017</Date>
        <Transaction>
          <BookNo>AA-111</BookNo>
          <Creditor>
            <PartyID>
              <ID schemeName="TaxIdentificationNo">5000</ID>
            </PartyID>
          </Creditor>
        </Transaction>
      </Payment>
    </Credit>
  </Data>
</SyncCredit>
```

The Creditor/PartyID/ID elements has to be sorted while keeping the other elements intact. However, I need to split out the sorted Creditor/PartyID/ID into each `<Payment>` node. I am using XSLT v2.0. Although, I am able to sort the Creditor/PartyID/ID properly using the `<xsl:perform-sort>` from the reference that I got, the output I get is like this:

```
<Payment>
  <Transaction xmlns="http://schema.XYZ.com/XYZOAGIS/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <BookNo>AA-111</BookNo>
    <Creditor>
      <PartyID>
        <ID schemeName="PassportNo">1000</ID>
      </PartyID>
    </Creditor>
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction xmlns="http://schema.XYZ.com/XYZOAGIS/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <BookNo>AA-111</BookNo>
    <Creditor>
      <PartyID>
        <ID schemeName="DriverLicense">2000</ID>
      </PartyID>
    </Creditor>
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction xmlns="http://schema.XYZ.com/XYZOAGIS/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <BookNo>AA-111</BookNo>
    <Creditor>
      <PartyID>
        <ID schemeName="BankPartyNo">4000</ID>
      </PartyID>
    </Creditor>
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction xmlns="http://schema.XYZ.com/XYZOAGIS/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <BookNo>AA-111</BookNo>
    <Creditor>
      <PartyID>
        <ID schemeName="TaxIdentificationNo">5000</ID>
      </PartyID>
    </Creditor>
  </Transaction>
```

This is my XSLT, it is not complete because I don't know how will I copy the elements under Header and from the Payment.I only tried doing the XSLT in the Transaction element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://schema.XYZ.com/XYZOAGIS/2">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="Transaction">
        <xsl:perform-sort select="SyncCredit/Data/Credit/Payment/Transaction">
            <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="Creditor/PartyID/ID"/>
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:variable>
    <Payment>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$Transaction"/>
    </Payment>
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us the XSLT that you've tried.

Comment: The question is not clear. Note that your output exhibits a different _structure_ than the input.  In the input each `<Payment>` contains _two_ `<Transaction>`s, but in the expected output each Transaction has been split out into its own Payment node.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: Thank you. I already edited my post and included the XSLT that I've created. Yes, you're correct. In input the Payment tag contains 2 Transaction tag. What I need is to sort the Creditor/PartyID/ID and in that I need to split out into its own Payment node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://schema.XYZ.com/XYZOAGIS/2"
xmlns="http://schema.XYZ.com/XYZOAGIS/2">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Credit">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Header"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Payment/Transaction">
            <xsl:sort select="Creditor/PartyID/ID" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Transaction">
    <Payment>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../ID, ../Date, ."/>
    </Payment>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, yes, your understanding is correct. Thank you so much for your feedback. Much appreciated. I've already got the expected output. Thank you so much.